# How to implement IP address merge in java

Tags: java, algorithm, ip, ip-address

Now I'm working on IP address segmentation toolkit. Bases on GeoIP database, in JAVA. The Function is allowed user to search IP address by area, and get the IP addresses as a result.

Now the program could search and generate the IP addresses after sorted as below

[image]

The picture is the result of "Asia".

I want to merge it, because it has around 25,000 IP addresses inside. it is too much for a switch, so i want to "merge" it into a smaller number.

The problem is I haven't find any suitable algorithm yet, completely have no ideas to merge the IP addresses in the result, cut down the number of ip addresses.

Any advice or suggestions, I would be appreciated that.

Comment: How do you "want to merge" it? What have you done so far? Where are you running into problems?

Comment: I'm sure the OP means to merge several overlapping CIDR ranges. Like [this perl example](https://gist.github.com/denji/17e30bddb9ce9e50294a). I don't know any Java implementation of this but this should be not too hard to translate this perl code into java.

Answer (score -2):

you may use xml or some structured document to organized, may look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <areas>
    <Asia>
       <ips>
       1.1.1.1
       1.1.1.2
       2.2.2.2
       </ips>
    </Asia>
  </areas>
</root>
```